# updating values in django template in html input?

Tags: javascript

I am making a shopping cart. I want to update the value as the user updates the input field.
Here is my code:

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th> 
  <td>${object['name']}</td> 
  <td>
    <input type="number" value=1 id=${object['id']}>
  </td>  
  <td>${object['price']*this.value}</td> 
</tr>
```

The input field has a default value of 1. In the last  tag, I am multiplying value by the price. I am using "this" keyword because I want to apply the multiplied amount to the same row.

It doesn't give me any error but it just prints "NaN" in the table not the figure.

Comment: This should show text only, Django variables use `{{ myvar }}` syntax, not `{ myvar }`

Comment: So probably you're using a Front-End framework, This seems like Svelte syntax tho, Can you please specify more details or fix any errors?

Comment: no it vanilla javascript.... and i am working with local storage objects ... i am not passing the object from the backend.

Comment: Okay np tags were kinda misleading